# How to realize with a serializer, when the admin user request, serialize all the fields, but the normal user request, serialize part fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to realize with a serializer, when the admin user request, serialize all the fields, but the normal user request, serialize part fields in Rest Framework?

In my serializers:

```
class UserListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    user serializer
    """
    account = AccountSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = [
            'password',
        ]
...

class AccountSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    user's accout
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        exclude = [
            'total_charge',
            'total_consume',
        ]
```

In the views:

```
 class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    """
    the user view 
    """
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_admin=False, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False).exclude(status=4)
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['username', 'qq', 'email']
    pagination_class = UserPageNumberPagination

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['-id']
```

My requirement is that when I use normal user request the APIView, I want to exclude the bellow fields:

```
'total_charge','total_consume'
```

If I use the admin user request the APIView, I want to serialize all the fields.

---

**EDIT**

I add the `get_serializer_class` merhod:

```
class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    """
    返回普通用户列表
    """
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_admin=False, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False).exclude(status=4)

    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['username', 'qq', 'email']
    pagination_class = UserPageNumberPagination

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['-id']

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return UserAdminListSerializer
        else:
            return UserListSerializer

    serializer_class = get_serializer_class()  # if I put this line in the front of `def get_serializer_class(self)` I will get not find error.
```

when I run the server, it get issue here:

The traceback:

```
 File "/Users/xsx/Desktop/xsx/Project/xss/qiyun_admin_usermanage/api/views.py", line 40, in <module>
    class UserListAPIView(ListAPIView):
  File "/Users/xsx/Desktop/xsx/Project/xss/qiyun_admin_usermanage/api/views.py", line 59, in UserListAPIView
    serializer_class = get_serializer_class()
TypeError: get_serializer_class() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: `serializer_class = get_serializer_class()` remove this line.

Comment: I have solved it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two serializers and override `get_serializer_class` in view like this.

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.user.is_superuser:
        return FullAccountSerializer
    return BasicAccountSerializer
```